# Why do I have the error: Given groups=1, weight of size [8, 1024, 1, 1], expected input[8, 304, 9, 40] to have 1024 channels, but got 304 channels

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, yolo, stereo-3d

I am working with [yolostereo3d](https://github.com/Owen-Liuyuxuan/visualDet3D) for stereo3d object detection (solely stereo camera, no velydone)on kitti dataset with [edgeNext](https://github.com/mmaaz60/EdgeNeXt) as the backbone instead of resNet.

Before changing the backbone from resNet to edgeNext with the same kitti dataset, everything was working fine. However, I started having the below error afterwards:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [8, 1024, 1, 1], expected input[8, 304, 9, 40] to have 1024 channels, but got 304 channels instead
```

Here is how I changed the backbone:

```
class YoloStereo3DCore(nn.Module):
    """
        Inference Structure of YoloStereo3D
        Similar to YoloMono3D,
        Left and Right image are fed into the backbone in batch. So they will affect each other with BatchNorm2d.
    """
    def __init__(self, backbone_arguments):
        f = open("/home/zakaseb/Thesis/YoloStereo3D/Stereo3D/Sequence.txt", "a")
        f.write("yolosterero3dCore_init \n")
        f.close()
        super(YoloStereo3DCore, self).__init__()
        self.backbone =edgenext_small(**backbone_arguments) # Resnet, change backbone from here

        base_features = 256 #if backbone_arguments['depth'] > 34 else 64 # meaning which depth of resnet
        self.neck = StereoMerging(base_features) #stereomerging outputs features and depth output.
```

Here is the edgenext_small()

```
@BACKBONE_DICT.register_module
def edgenext_small(pretrained=False, **kwargs):
    FPS @ BS=1: 93.84 & @ BS=256: 1785.92 for MobileViT_S
    model = EdgeNeXt(depths=[3, 3, 9, 3], dims=[48, 96, 160, 304], expan_ratio=4,
                     global_block=[0, 1, 1, 1],
                     global_block_type=['None', 'SDTA', 'SDTA', 'SDTA'],
                     use_pos_embd_xca=[False, True, False, False],
                     kernel_sizes=[3, 5, 7, 9],
                     d2_scales=[2, 2, 3, 4],
                     classifier_dropout=0.0)

    return model
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see your backbone returns feature map with 304 channels but the next layer expect 1024 channels. For now there are two solutions:

- If your backbone is designed from scratch you can adapt its architecture such that `dims` argument of `EdgeNeXt` ends with 1024. Typically:

```py
model = EdgeNeXt(depths=[3, 3, 9, 3], dims=[48, 96, 160, 1024], expan_ratio=4,
                 global_block=[0, 1, 1, 1],
                 global_block_type=['None', 'SDTA', 'SDTA', 'SDTA'],
                 use_pos_embd_xca=[False, True, False, False],
                 kernel_sizes=[3, 5, 7, 9],
                 d2_scales=[2, 2, 3, 4],
                 classifier_dropout=0.0)
```

- If your backbone has a fixed architecture (for instance if you are using a pre-trained model), you should adapt the architecture after the backbone. For instance you can add a `torch.Conv2D(304, 1024, kernel_size)` to learn 1024 features from the 304. Otherwise you can change the architecture of the next layer.

Comment: I've actually managed to just hard-code the number of channels in both the backbone and the detector. but I got another error concerning the masking dimension. So I undid it thinking they were correlated. From what I'm seeing, it turns out they're not. As for adding a further convolution, as it's intrusive to the architecture I will leave it as last resort. Thanks!